# page break after two divs ruby

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm generating a PDF with postcards on it, and there should be two postcards per page.  Currently I am looping through my object with an index, and then telling it to page break `if idx % 2 == 0`.  Although this solution isn't working for me at all. Is my logic solid, or is my CSS not correct?

Here is my code so far:

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @postcards.each_with_index do |name, idx| %>
    <% if idx % 2 == 0 %>
        <div class = "page-break"></div>
    <% end %>
    <div class = "postcards-container">
        <%= image_tag "badge_logo.png", :id => 'agency-badge' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**CSS:**

```
.postcards-container {

    width: 600px;
    height: 390px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    //padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

#agency-badge {
            width: 140px;
            height: 75px;
        }

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
}
```

Comment: According to your code, you are actually using `idx % 1 == 0` not `idx % 2 == 0`

Comment: that wasnt supposed to be there.  Problem still exists with `idx % 2 == 0 `

Comment: Well ... Aren't you creating **several** div with a **unique identifier** `#page-break` for all of them? Shouldn't you be using a CSS class instead?

Comment: @MrYoshiji yes you are correct, but that shouldnt be causing it to not page break?

Comment: Why would it not cause it? It depends on how each browser interpret bad HTML : maybe Chrome would apply the style to every div with id `page-break` but Opera would not. Can't be predictible (also a div is by default `display: block` unless you overwrite it)

Comment: Have you tried to direclty use `<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>` to see if the issue comes from the linked css file or from the PDF generator itself?

Comment: @MrYoshiji good call on the inline css.  I got it page breaking, but with a blank first page.  Anywho, good call.

Comment: That is because `0 % 2 == 0` returns `true` ;-) check also if `idx > 0`

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished quite easily with jQuery (or vanilla JS).

This approach keeps the logic out of your views which is considered to be a better approach than inserting logic in your views.

ERB:

```
<% @postcards.each do %>
  <div class="postcard">
    <%= whatever content you want to display for each post card %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

JS:

```
$('.postcard:even').addClass('page-break');
```

CSS:

```
@media print {
  .page-break {
    display: block; 
    page-break-before: always; 
  }
}
```